# Does a purely Euclidean proof that an orientation preserving isometry is either a translation or a rotation about some point, exist?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, isometry

In his book ALGEBRA, $2^{\text{nd}}$ ed., Artin proves (Ch. 6 - Symmetry, Lemma 6.3.5) that an
orientation preserving isometry $f$ that has the form $m=t_a \rho_\theta$ with $\theta \neq0$, is a rotation through the angle $\theta$ about a point in the plane. He does so by proving the existence of a point $p$ in the plane about which $f$ is a rotation; $p=(I-\rho_\theta)^{-1}a$ . So far, so good.

Now, he gives a geometrical construction that is solely based on Book I of Euclid's elements, to find $p$, given the vector $a$ and the angle $\theta$.

> The point $p$ is the fixed point of the isometry $t_a \rho_\theta$, and it can be found geometrically, as illustrated below. The line $l$ passes through the origin and is perpendicular to the vector $a$ (Euc. I.12). The sector with angle $\theta$ is situated so as to be bisected by $l$ (Euc. I.8, I.9) and the fixed point $p$ is determined by inserting the vector $a$ into the sector, as shown. [image: Fixed point of isometry]

Now if I took an arbitrary point $P$, rotated it anticlockwise by $\theta$ with respect to $O$ to get $P'$ and then translated $P'$ by the vector $a$ to get $P''$ ; instead if I rotated $P$ w.r.t. $p$ to get $Q$, then $P''$ and $Q$ would coincide. This is indeed true by theorem (and I verified with actual construction too.) However, I think it (this last result) can be proved by Euclidean system of axioms and postulates too, but I can't figure out more than that the triangles $PpQ$, $POP'$ and $pOq$ are all similar.

Comment: Proof outline for plane: there are 3 cases. Either the perpendicular bisectors of the segment connecting each point to its isometric image are the same, in which case the isometry is easily seen to be a reflection, or they are all parallel, in which case the segments are parallel and by congurent triangles the same length, thus a translation, or else at least two bisectors intersect in a point $O$. All bisectors must pass through $O$, which is unmoved by the isometry. All points are the same distance from $O$ as their isometric images. The isometry is a rotation.